# Play 1.2.5 + Activiti (BPM) restful + authentication

Tags: authentication, playframework, playframework-1.x, basic-authentication, activiti

Hopefully some of you would have stumbled into and hopefully through the above.

**First let me start with my problem:**

I need to authenticate the current logged in user in play on the activity restful service

This entails me using (in my case) the restlet client api to create a http connection to the restful activiti api which requires user authentication.

```
Reference reference = new Reference(Play.configuration.getProperty("activiti.rest.url") + "/tasks?assignee=kermit");
Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTP);
Request request = new Request(Method.GET, reference);
request.setChallengeResponse(new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "kermit", "kermit"));
```

This works fine and returns all as needed.

**The issue:**

I`m looking for a way to pass the web username/password into the above code.

1. As i have the logged in name via *Security.isConnected()* i just need to save the password in the cache perhaps and do a cleanup at some point.
2. Potentially build some soft of single sign-on solution in the controllers.Security.java class to generate a token and then extend activity to accept this token rather
3. Looking to you distinguished individuals for a better solution

I dont feel like keeping the password if i dont need to and have searched through activity documentation. Seems they only support basic auth. 
The restlet api does support oauth and the sorts but i cant find examples that activiti has it implemented or for custom implemenation.

Any advice/comments welcome.

Regards
Derick